# Wrong Static Method

Tags: php, static

`PHP` calls private method in parent class instead of method define in current class called by `call_user_func`

```
class Car {
    public function run() {
        return call_user_func(array('Toyota','getName')); // should call toyota
    }
    private static function getName() {
        return 'Car';
    }
}

class Toyota extends Car {
    public static function getName() {
        return 'Toyota';
    }
}

$car = new Car();
echo $car->run(); //Car instead of Toyota

$toyota = new Toyota();
echo $toyota->run(); //Car instead of Toyota
```

Comment: Why is the getName() function private in Car and public in Toyota?

Comment: Which version of php are you using? Because on PHP 5.4 it echos `Toyota` twice instead of `Car`. If I understood correctly in your case it happens contrary.

Comment: Seem to vary widely across different PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/ekaEs - Bugs in PHP! The world must truly be ending.

Comment: @user1615903 that should not be allowed in the first place

Comment: Or simply another _phpwtf_.

Comment: @deceze its crazy to know it has been there since `PHP 5.3.0`

Comment: Thou abominable static method: die a thousand deaths and curse my conscience no longer.  The pure Holy Language of PHP must be purged of such wretched filth.

Comment: @Levi `static` methods are fine and useful in OOP, thou shalt simply not abuseth them. :)

Comment: Your code prints "ToyotaToyota".

Comment: @LeviMorrison I always replace all `static` methods with `goto` labels. I hate to see utility methods stored in a class.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your question is, or even if you actually want an answer.  There are answers below dating back as far as December with feedback from OP.  Requests by comment for additional information that have gone answered.  Is this simply here to point out flaws in PHP?

Comment: @PhillSparks i want a solution that uses `call_user_func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that appears to have fluctuated in and out of existence for a long time (see @deceze's tests in comments on the question). It is possible to "fix" this issue - that is, give consistent behaviour across PHP versions - using [reflection](http://php.net/reflection):

Works in PHP 5.3.2 and later due to a dependency on [`ReflectionMethod::setAccessible()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php) to invoke private/protected methods. I will add further explanation for this code, what it can and can't do and how it works very shortly.

Unfortunately it's not possible to test this directly on 3v4l.org because the code is too large, however this is the first ever real use case for [minifying](http://customhost.com.ua/php-minify/index.php) PHP code - it does work on 3v4l if you do this, so feel free to play around and see if you can break it. The only issue I'm aware of is that it doesn't currently understand `parent`. It is also restricted by the lack of `$this` support in closures before 5.4, there's not really anything that can be done about this though.

```
<?php

function call_user_func_fixed()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $callable = array_shift($args);
    return call_user_func_array_fixed($callable, $args);
}

function call_user_func_array_fixed($callable, $args)
{
    $isStaticMethod = false;
    $expr = '/^([a-z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*)::([a-z_\x7f-\xff][\w\x7f-\xff]*)$/i';

    // Extract the callable normalized to an array if it looks like a method call
    if (is_string($callable) && preg_match($expr, $callable, $matches)) {
        $func = array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    } else if (is_array($callable)
                   && count($callable) === 2
                   && isset($callable[0], $callable[1])
                   && (is_string($callable[0]) || is_object($callable[0]))
                   && is_string($callable[1])) {
        $func = $callable;
    }

    // If we're not interested in it use the regular mechanism
    if (!isset($func)) {
        return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
    }

    $backtrace = debug_backtrace(); // passing args here is fraught with complications for backwards compat :-(
    if ($backtrace[1]['function'] === 'call_user_func_fixed') {
        $called = 'call_user_func_fixed';
        $contextKey = 2;
    } else {
        $called = 'call_user_func_array_fixed';
        $contextKey = 1;
    }

    try {
        // Get a reference to the target static method if possible
        switch (true) {
            case $func[0] === 'self':
            case $func[0] === 'static':
                if (!isset($backtrace[$contextKey]['object'])) {
                    throw new Exception('Use of self:: in an invalid context');
                }

                $contextClass = new ReflectionClass($backtrace[$contextKey][$func[0] === 'self' ? 'class' : 'object']);
                $contextClassName = $contextClass->getName();

                $method = $contextClass->getMethod($func[1]);
                $ownerClassName = $method->getDeclaringClass()->getName();
                if (!$method->isStatic()) {
                    throw new Exception('Attempting to call instance method in a static context');
                }
                $invokeContext = null;

                if ($method->isPrivate()) {
                    if ($ownerClassName !== $contextClassName
                            || !method_exists($method, 'setAccessible')) {
                        throw new Exception('Attempting to call private method in an invalid context');
                    }

                    $method->setAccessible(true);
                } else if ($method->isProtected()) {
                    if (!method_exists($method, 'setAccessible')) {
                        throw new Exception('Attempting to call protected method in an invalid context');
                    }

                    while ($contextClass->getName() !== $ownerClassName) {
                        $contextClass = $contextClass->getParentClass();
                    }
                    if ($contextClass->getName() !== $ownerClassName) {
                        throw new Exception('Attempting to call protected method in an invalid context');
                    }

                    $method->setAccessible(true);
                }

                break;

            case is_object($func[0]):
                $contextClass = new ReflectionClass($func[0]);
                $contextClassName = $contextClass->getName();

                $method = $contextClass->getMethod($func[1]);
                $ownerClassName = $method->getDeclaringClass()->getName();

                if ($method->isStatic()) {
                    $invokeContext = null;

                    if ($method->isPrivate()) {
                        if ($ownerClassName !== $contextClassName || !method_exists($method, 'setAccessible')) {
                            throw new Exception('Attempting to call private method in an invalid context');
                        }

                        $method->setAccessible(true);
                    } else if ($method->isProtected()) {
                        if (!method_exists($method, 'setAccessible')) {
                            throw new Exception('Attempting to call protected method in an invalid context');
                        }

                        while ($contextClass->getName() !== $ownerClassName) {
                            $contextClass = $contextClass->getParentClass();
                        }
                        if ($contextClass->getName() !== $ownerClassName) {
                            throw new Exception('Attempting to call protected method in an invalid context');
                        }

                        $method->setAccessible(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    $invokeContext = $func[0];
                }

                break;

            default:
                $contextClass = new ReflectionClass($backtrace[$contextKey]['object']);
                $method = new ReflectionMethod($func[0], $func[1]);
                $ownerClassName = $method->getDeclaringClass()->getName();
                if (!$method->isStatic()) {
                    throw new Exception('Attempting to call instance method in a static context');
                }
                $invokeContext = null;

                if ($method->isPrivate()) {
                    if (empty($backtrace[$contextKey]['object'])
                            || $func[0] !== $contextClass->getName()
                            || !method_exists($method, 'setAccessible')) {
                        throw new Exception('Attempting to call private method in an invalid context');
                    }

                    $method->setAccessible(true);
                } else if ($method->isProtected()) {
                    $contextClass = new ReflectionClass($backtrace[$contextKey]['object']);

                    if (empty($backtrace[$contextKey]['object']) || !method_exists($method, 'setAccessible')) {
                        throw new Exception('Attempting to call protected method outside a class context');
                    }

                    while ($contextClass->getName() !== $ownerClassName) {
                        $contextClass = $contextClass->getParentClass();
                    }
                    if ($contextClass->getName() !== $ownerClassName) {
                        throw new Exception('Attempting to call protected method in an invalid context');
                    }

                    $method->setAccessible(true);
                }

                break;
        }

        // Invoke the method with the passed arguments and return the result
        return $method->invokeArgs($invokeContext, $args);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        trigger_error($called . '() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback: ' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Baba added note to the first paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution with a different approach..

```
<?php
 class Car {
    public static function run() {
     return static::getName();
   }
   private static function getName() {
    return 'Car';
    }
  }

   class Toyota extends Car {
     public static function getName() {
        return 'Toyota';
      }
   }
echo Car::run();
echo Toyota::run();
  ?>
```

Using `Late Static Binding`..

Answer (score 3):

You might use something like this:

```
<?php

class Car {
    public function run() {
        return static::getName();
    }

    private static function getName(){
        return 'Car';
    }
}

class Toyota extends Car {
    public static function getName(){
        return 'Toyota';
    }
}

$car = new Car();
echo $car->run();

echo PHP_EOL;

$toyota = new Toyota();
echo $toyota->run();

?>
```

Output:

```
Car
Toyota
```

PHP 5.4.5

Answer (score 1):

Use "protected" modifier if you want to get access from parent and descendants only. IMO, it's obvious. For example:

```
<?php

class Car {
    public function run() {
        return call_user_func(array('static','getName'));
    }
    protected static function getName() {
        return 'Car';
    }
}

class Toyota extends Car {
    protected static function getName() {
        return 'Toyota';
    }
}

$car = new Car();
echo $car->run(); // "Car"

$toyota = new Toyota();
echo $toyota->run(); // "Toyota"
```

You can use get_called_class() instead of 'static'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, I think, with the different access levels of the two getname functions.  If you make the base class version of getname() public (the same as the derived class version), then in php 5.3.15 (on my Mac), you get Toyota.  I think that, because of the different access levels, you end up with two different versions of the getname() function in the Toyota class, rather than the derived class version overriding the base class version. In other words, you have overloading rather than overriding.  Therefore, when the run() function looks for a getname() function in the Toyota class to execute, it finds two and takes the first one, which would be the first to be declared (from the base class).

Granted this is just supposition on my part, but it sounds plausible.

Answer (score 0):

use the get_called_called function todo this

```
public function run() {
    $self = get_called_class();
    return $self::getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're functions are overriding each other and by default going to the first one. Unless you change the parameters of one function, or rename the function it will always default to the parent class function.